# How to change clientId (&cid) in Google Tag Manager iOS?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager, gtm-oauth2

I need to change the &cid (client Id) parameter in Google Tag Manager. I have tried setting `kGAIClientId` on tracker of `GAI` (Google Analytics).

```
self.tracker =[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GAProperty_VALUE];
[self.tracker set:kGAIClientId value:NEW_VALUE];
```

doesn't work!

I have also tried pushing `&cid` in data layer with new value, doesn't work.

Here is what i get in logs:

```
GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:517): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_s" = 86;
        "&_u" = ".7nL";
        "&_v" = "mi3.1.4";
        "&a" = 240807461;
        "&aid" = "***";             // removed
        "&an" = "***";              // removed
        "&av" = "2.6.5";
        "&cd" = "***";              // removed
        "&cd1" = "***";
        "&cd10" = unknown;
        "&cd11" = no;
        "&cd15" = "/home/";
        "&cd41" = iOS;
        "&cid" = "7c5824a7-5851-4829-a6c9-0a09a11fbe98";
        "&dm" = "x86_64";
        "&ds" = app;
        "&sr" = 750x1334;
        "&t" = appview;
        "&tid" = "***";             // removed
        "&ul" = "en-us";
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = "***";
        gaiVersion = "3.14";
    };
    timestamp = "2016-02-17 09:27:12 +0000";
}
```

If anyone knows how to change it, please help!

Thank you.

Comment: did you get solution?

Comment: Yes, in the payload dictionary, use "c_idfa" key to modify it.

Comment: thanks...could you please explain how did you change? I would be good if you add this as an answer because there are very few information about this on Google Analytics.